# PHP foreach by reference causes weird glitch when going through array of objects

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array of objects.  The objects mainly have a bunch of
properties because these are meta-data objects.

so it is like
`$objects[]` is like a bunch of items that have properties like:
`object->item1`, `object->item2`, etc.

I want to add something to each of these objects, so...

```
foreach ($objects as &$object) {
  $object->newItem=(something I compute);
}
```

then later, I want to display these objects as a list in html.  So, I go:

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  <li><?php object output stuff here ?></li>
}
```

ok.  Now, it works fine, except the last object is discarded and the
second to last object is displayed twice.  WTF??

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3307409

Answer (score 39):

If you iterate by reference, always unset the iteration variable afterwards:

```
foreach ($objects as &$object) {
      // some code
}
unset($object);
```

Excerpt from the [`foreach` documentation](http://php.net/foreach):

> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

If you want to understand why your code behaves the way it behaves, here is some further reading: [References and foreach](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html)

Comment: +1 for answering the question, but he doesnt really need to loop by reference since he is working with objects... does he?

Comment: @prodigitalson: Yep, you're right. ^^ I'm always thinking too comlicated

Comment: haha.. it happens (to me more often than id liek to admit). you did answer the question though which is important when one does need to loop by reference.

Comment: Thank you!  I was tearing my hair out about this.  I actually wrote a workaround in the meantime, but I've come across this weirdness a few times and never understood it.  GREAT link BTW.

Comment: @Brenn: If this answer answers your question, you should accept it, by clicking on the green tick next to it :)

Comment: @NikiC, (@Brenn) Was also just tearing my hair out over this one. Learned something valuable tonight- would up vote this twice if I could.

Answer (score 4):

Objects are always references, so just remove the '&'

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  $object->newItem=(something I compute);
}

foreach ($objects as $object) {
  echo "<li>{$object->someResult()}</li>";
}
```

I know you already got your answer, but this might help other devs find it faster.