# Convert column integer values into date expressions

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I've a following associative array named `$data`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transaction_user_id] => 359691e27b23f8ef3f8e1c50315cd506
            [transaction_no] => 19500912050218
            [transaction_total_amount] => 589.00
            [transaction_date] => 1335932419
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transaction_user_id] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
            [transaction_no] => 36010512050819
            [transaction_total_amount] => 79.00
            [transaction_date] => 1336476696
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [transaction_user_id] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
            [transaction_no] => 19020512050820
            [transaction_total_amount] => 299.00
            [transaction_date] => 1336476739
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [transaction_user_id] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
            [transaction_no] => 27050512050821
            [transaction_total_amount] => 79.00
            [transaction_date] => 1336476927
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [transaction_user_id] => 8e9050a3646c98342b9ba079fba80982
            [transaction_no] => 12070512050822
            [transaction_total_amount] => 129.00
            [transaction_date] => 1336477032
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )

)
```

and I want to convert the value of key `[transaction_date]` into user readable format (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy). For that I written the following code in a function which returns the whole array:

```
 foreach($data as $value)
 {
    $value[transaction_date]=date('d/m/Y',$value[transaction_date]);
 }
    
 return $data;
```

My problem is I'm getting the same array without changing the value of `[transaction_date]` for all the array elements. Actually array with updated values for `[transaction_date]` is expected to be returned.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: You have to use quotes around your key names!

Comment: Coming from javascript, this seems like a hard procedure to adapt to php for simple tasks

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Change your foreach to something like this, You are not assigning data back to your return variable `$data` after performing operation on that.

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
  $data[$key]['transaction_date'] = date('d/m/Y',$value['transaction_date']);
}
```

[Codepad DEMO.](http://codepad.org/diDxHLmS)

Comment: Updating the foreach variable array within its scope will not alter its value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810168/php-foreach-by-reference-causes-weird-glitch-when-going-through-array-of-objects

Answer (score 46):

This will work too!

```
foreach($data as &$value) {
  $value['transaction_date'] = date('d/m/Y', $value['transaction_date']);
}
```

Yay for alternatives!

Comment: this is the correct answer .. you need a &amp; - the other way (accepted) is sort of a subtle "hack" - i.e the `accepted answer` by @Rikesh works `indirectly` for reasons that are not obvious, i.e. to many it might look like a) works, but actually b) is happening, when you needed c) all along.. @naomik's answer is the right one "c)" and while "a)" will work it is not the way to go

Answer (score 21):

PHP [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function is specifically for altering array.

Try this:

```
array_walk ( $data, function (&$key) { 
    $key["transaction_date"] = date('d/m/Y',$key["transaction_date"]); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this in my own case, to change a certain value in an associative array, by slightly modifying it: array_walk($users, function(&$key) { if ($key['name'] == 'John') $key['name'] = 'Jack'; }); In other words, in users array, change user name to Jack, if it is John.

Answer (score 9):

Use array_walk_recursive function for multi-denominational array.

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$v, $k) { 
    if($k == 'transaction_date'){ 
        $v = date('d/m/Y',$v); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Recursively iterate over a multi religious denomination, got it ^^

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is using a lambda within "array_walk" native function to make the required changes:

```
    array_walk($data, function (&$value, $key) {
            if($key == 'transaction_date'){ 
                  $value = date('d/m/Y', $value); 
            }
    });
```

The value is updated in the array as it's passed with as a reference "&".

Answer (score 1):

This a single solution, in where **your_field** is a field that will set and **new_value** is a new value field, that can a function or a single value

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
   $item["your_field"] = "new_value";
   $array[$key] = $item;
}
```

In your case **new_value** will be a date() function

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data as $value)
{
    $value["transaction_date"] = date('d/m/Y',$value["transaction_date"]);
}
return $data;
```

Comment: This doesn't work because you didn't use `as &$value`! See my answer for details!

Comment: This doesn't work because, you not set the element in array, with the new value