# Update Meta Box Value With Some WordPress Function. Possible?

Tags: php, wordpress

**Question:** Is it possible to update the meta box value of a WordPress post using some function like we do with update_post_meta()?

**Explanation:**
Here is the format of the data saved in database for the metabox I want to update with a function/hook.
[image]

Now, if I want to update just a *single entry* from that data, let say **'start_year'** then how can I do that using a function/hook?

If I choose to go with update_post_meta(65, '_mycpt_date', ''2010), it will obviously replace everything with just '2010'.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of brainstorming and with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472033/how-to-update-specific-keys-value-in-an-associative-array-in-php) I did it with a little bit of workaround.

```
// Storing the value/array in the variable.
   $options = get_post_meta( 65, '_chronos_date', true);

// Updating the new value using key-value pair. That way, other parts of the array would remain un-touched.
  $options['start_year']= "2000";

// Update the new value.
update_post_meta(65,'_chronos_date',$options);
```

It was quick. I hope it'd help someone else.