# Same operation, different result

Tags: php, arrays, reference, count, cursor

My goal is to convert an array (with sub-arrays) to a HTML table. To do that, I have to calculate some rowspan.
First, let give you the var_dump of my array called $table :

```
array(3) {
  ["BOUYGUES TELECOM"]=>          /* Mobile carrier */
  array(4) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(5) "72967"
    ["date_ok"]=>
    string(10) "04/10/1996"
    ["date_ok_edit"]=>
    string(10) "20/09/2013"
    ["azimuth"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["66.00"]=>                /* Azimuth of an antenna */
      array(1) {
        ["26.00"]=>              /* Height (from floor) of the antenna */
        array(1) {
          ["FH"]=>               /* System/Technology used */
          array(1) {
            [0]=>                /* Ranges of frequencies */
            string(18) "37.26 à 37.50 GHz"
          }
        }
      }
      ["80.00"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["26.00"]=>
        array(5) {
          ["GSM 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1758.30 à 1784.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1853.30 à 1879.90 MHz"
          }
          ["GSM 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "880.10 à 889.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "925.10 à 934.90 MHz"
          }
          ["LTE 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1765.00 à 1785.00 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1860.00 à 1880.00 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 2100"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1900.10 à 1905.10 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1935.30 à 1950.10 MHz"
            [2]=>
            string(22) "2125.30 à 2140.10 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "880.10 à 889.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "925.10 à 934.90 MHz"
          }
        }
      }
      ["180.00"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["26.00"]=>
        array(5) {
          ["GSM 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1758.30 à 1784.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1853.30 à 1879.90 MHz"
          }
          ["GSM 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "880.10 à 889.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "925.10 à 934.90 MHz"
          }
          ["LTE 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1765.00 à 1785.00 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1860.00 à 1880.00 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 2100"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1900.10 à 1905.10 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1935.30 à 1950.10 MHz"
            [2]=>
            string(22) "2125.30 à 2140.10 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "880.10 à 889.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "925.10 à 934.90 MHz"
          }
        }
      }
      ["280.00"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["26.00"]=>
        array(5) {
          ["GSM 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1758.30 à 1784.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1853.30 à 1879.90 MHz"
          }
          ["GSM 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "880.10 à 889.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "925.10 à 934.90 MHz"
          }
          ["LTE 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1765.00 à 1785.00 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1860.00 à 1880.00 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 2100"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1900.10 à 1905.10 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1935.30 à 1950.10 MHz"
            [2]=>
            string(22) "2125.30 à 2140.10 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "880.10 à 889.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "925.10 à 934.90 MHz"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["ORANGE"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(6) "320884"
    ["date_ok"]=>
    string(10) "11/07/2003"
    ["date_ok_edit"]=>
    string(10) "06/07/2007"
    ["azimuth"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["0.00"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["23.00"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["GSM 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1713.10 à 1736.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1808.10 à 1831.90 MHz"
          }
          ["GSM 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "890.10 à 902.50 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "935.10 à 947.50 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 2100"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1910.10 à 1915.10 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1964.90 à 1979.70 MHz"
            [2]=>
            string(22) "2154.90 à 2169.70 MHz"
          }
        }
      }
      ["120.00"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["23.00"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["GSM 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1713.10 à 1736.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1808.10 à 1831.90 MHz"
          }
          ["GSM 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "890.10 à 902.50 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "935.10 à 947.50 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 2100"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1910.10 à 1915.10 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1964.90 à 1979.70 MHz"
            [2]=>
            string(22) "2154.90 à 2169.70 MHz"
          }
        }
      }
      ["240.00"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["23.00"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["GSM 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1713.10 à 1736.90 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1808.10 à 1831.90 MHz"
          }
          ["GSM 900"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(20) "890.10 à 902.50 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(20) "935.10 à 947.50 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 2100"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1910.10 à 1915.10 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1964.90 à 1979.70 MHz"
            [2]=>
            string(22) "2154.90 à 2169.70 MHz"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["SFR"]=>
  &array(4) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(6) "453640"
    ["date_ok"]=>
    string(10) "25/05/2007"
    ["date_ok_edit"]=>
    string(10) "23/04/2010"
    ["azimuth"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["165.00"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["25.00"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["GSM 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1710.00 à 1785.00 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1805.00 à 1880.00 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 2100"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1915.10 à 1920.10 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1920.50 à 1935.30 MHz"
            [2]=>
            string(22) "2110.50 à 2125.30 MHz"
          }
        }
      }
      ["243.20"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["27.60"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["FH"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(18) "37.26 à 37.50 GHz"
          }
        }
      }
      ["280.00"]=>
      &array(1) {
        ["25.00"]=>
        &array(2) {
          ["GSM 1800"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1710.00 à 1785.00 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1805.00 à 1880.00 MHz"
          }
          ["UMTS 2100"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            string(22) "1915.10 à 1920.10 MHz"
            [1]=>
            string(22) "1920.50 à 1935.30 MHz"
            [2]=>
            string(22) "2110.50 à 2125.30 MHz"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this function calculates how many lines are needed for a (mobile) carrier.

```
function nbRowsForCarrier($carrier){
    global $table;

    $nb_lines = 0;

    foreach( $table[$carrier]['azimuth'] as $azimuth => $heights ){
        foreach( $heights as $height => $systems ){
            foreach( $systems as $system ){
                $nb_lines += count($system); 
            }
        }
    }   

    return $nb_lines;
}
```

So, if I call nbRowsForCarrier("SFR"), it returns 11. (Because 11 ranges of frequencies for SFR)
The problem is that this result changes when it is called from a foreach :

```
foreach( $table as $carrier => $details ){
    echo nbRowsForCarrier($carrier); // When $carrier="SFR", it returns 13 instead of 11.
    [...Other operations...]
}
```

For the others carriers "BOUYGUES TELECOM" and "ORANGE", it works properly. But it doesn't for "SFR".
I highly suspect the references to be the problem (Note that in the var_dump, there are some "&" before "array" in SFR arrays)
Maybe a problem of cursor... I tried to play with reset() but without success...

Is there a way to copy this array to an other variable without referencing (that causing problems, I think) ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if "SFR" arrays are referenced (the "&" before "array"), that's because I made a ksort() to sort keys alphabetically.
To remove the "&" before "array", I then get it working, I seen this : [PHP foreach by reference causes weird glitch when going through array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810168/php-foreach-by-reference-causes-weird-glitch-when-going-through-array-of-objects)

In my case, When I have to sort by systems, I have to do that:

```
// Sort by system
foreach( $table as $carrier => &$info_carrier ){
    foreach( $info_carrier['azimuth'] as &$heights ){
        foreach( $heights as $height => &$systems ){
            ksort($systems);
        }
        unset($systems); // WHAT I ADDED TO GET IT WORKING
    }
    unset($heights); // WHAT I ADDED TO GET IT WORKING
}
unset($info_carrier); // WHAT I ADDED TO GET IT WORKING
```

And then it works!