# update a global array within a function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a global array in which I am trying to update a value (remain persistent) and then display it.
I get no error but the array never gets updated.

```
<?php
$anchor = 'bird';
$stuff = array('apple', 'bird', 'frog');

function insert($anchor, $stuff){
    foreach($stuff as $part){
        $new_array = array($anchor => rand());
        if($part == $anchor){
            array_push($stuff, $new_array);
        }
    }
}

for($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++){
    insert($anchor, $stuff);
    var_dump($stuff);
}
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "bird"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "frog"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "bird"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "frog"
}
```

expected output:

> {'bird' => 674568765}
>   {'bird' => 986266261}

How do I update an array within a function, so that the changes are reflected globally (persistent)?

Comment: PHP variables are passed into functions *by value* not by reference.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879/are-php-variables-passed-by-value-or-by-reference#885

Comment: To update the original array, you'll need to return a value from the function and assign it to the array variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the variable `$stuff` by reference. Note the `&` in the function parameters.

```
function insert($anchor, &$stuff){    // note the & mark
        foreach($stuff as $part){
                $new_array = array($anchor => rand());
                if($part == $anchor){
                        array_push($stuff, $new_array);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: It says I have to wait 6min to click.

Comment: Do you have a doc on the particulars of why I need a pointer there?  That has been blowing my mind  (I am assuming that is a pointer, I never played with one on PHP)

Comment: Refere this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879/are-php-variables-passed-by-value-or-by-reference

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned: by default, PHP [function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) are passed *by value*, meaning that a value changed inside a function does not change outside of the function.

I suggest [returning](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) the new `$stuff` value from your function:

```
<?php

$anchor = 'bird';
$stuff = array('apple', 'bird', 'frog');

function insert($anchor, $stuff){
  foreach($stuff as $part){
    $new_array = array($anchor => rand());
    if($part == $anchor){
      array_push($stuff, $new_array);
    }
  }
  return $stuff;
}

for($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++){
  $stuff=insert($anchor, $stuff);
}

echo"<pre>".print_r($stuff,true)."</pre>";

?>
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => bird
    [2] => frog
    [3] => Array
        (
            [bird] => 618490127
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [bird] => 1869073273
        )

)
```

---

Other solutions propose [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), to which I'm not opposed. But I have definitely run into buggy code in which it wasn't immediately clear that a function was changing a value, and I've been confused by [unexpected loop behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810168/php-foreach-by-reference-causes-weird-glitch-when-going-through-array-of-objects). As a result, I generally prefer arguably more readable/maintainable code that returns a new value.

See [When to pass-by-reference in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157799/when-to-pass-by-reference-in-php).
[Get technical with Sara Golemon](http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html#badrefs).

Comment: This is, I believe, safer than declaring the function with reference parameters.

Comment: @JonathanM They would actually be pretty much the same. Neither one is "safer" that the other. There are no exploits or issues with using a reference that wouldn't exist making a copy. By reference would actually just not make a copy of the array which would be better if you are dealing with a very large amount of data.

Comment: In terms of API, I think it's better for functions to return changed values than to change them by reference. That way the programmer doesn't unknowingly get a changed value. Less likely to have a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you want changes to a variable that you pass to a function to persist after the function ends, pass the variable by reference:

Change:

```
function insert($anchor, $stuff)
```

To

```
function insert($anchor, &$stuff)
```