# attempting to assign a property to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called `$my_array` . 
I created $my_array like this:

```
 $my_array = [];
 $my_array[0] = [];
 $my_array[1] = [];
 $my_array[2] = [];
 $my_array[3] = [];
```

Each element of `$my_array` is an array:

```
foreach ($my_array as $array){
    print(gettype($array));
    print(" ///   ");
}
```

output: `array ///   array ///   array ///   array ///`

```
foreach ($my_array as $array){


    $array['link_root'] = "a string";

    print($array['link_root']);
    print("     /////     ");
}
```

output is: `a string     /////     a string     /////     a string     /////     a string     /////`

and then when I try:

```
print($my_array[0]['link_root'])
```

I get: `PHP error:  Undefined index: link_root`

How do I iteratively set a value for a key/property of an array and why is this not working?

Comment: Try a `print_r()` or a `var_dump()` first to see whats in array `$my_array`.. Secondly, the array you're trying to write to while looping is a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foreach` control structure does not pass the value by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) by default.

If you want to be able modify the array internally, you need to use `&` to indicate you want it passed as a reference like so:

```
foreach ($myArray as &$array) {
    $array['link_root'] = "a string";
}

print($myArray[0]['link_root']);
```

The difference is subtle. Another way to do this is pass the index and reference it directly like:

```
foreach ($myArray as $index => $array) {
    $myArray[$index]['link_root'] = "a string";
}

print($myArray[0]['link_root']);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I believe there where some implications using the refference method, I can't recall what they where though.

Comment: @Xorifelse Probably about unsetting the variable after the loop to avoid modifying the main array by accident when you re-use the loop variable later on.

Comment: @jeroen I found it, you need to [unset](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5810200/4982088) after foreach otherwise it can cause undesired behavior.

Comment: Good point! Thanks for pointing that out, I had forgotten that.

Comment: @Xorifelse Exactly :-)