# PHP - array unset not working in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have various items in my $positions array and do the following:

```
foreach ($positions as &$position) {

    if ($position['date'] == $order['date']) {
        unset($position);
    }
}
var_dump($positions);
```

The var_dump still displays the $position which should be excluded.

When I do

```
foreach ($positions as $key => &$position) {
    if ($position['date'] == $order['date']) {
        unset($positions[$key]);
    }    
}
```

It does remove far more items than expected.

Anybody knows what happens here in both cases and how why does unset($position) not work? I reference the item in the foreach loop with '&'.

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing `&` from the second attempt.

Comment: You could try [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

Comment: I think I got it. It does remove more items than expected in the second case, because some values are stored like this "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000" in the database as the datetime, but I expected everything has a valid date or NULL.

Comment: `$positions = array_filter($positions, function($x) { return $x['date'] != '1'; });`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using &$variableName use $varibaleName, because there is not concept of pointers in php and not proper used of reference operator causes unexpected results sometimes.

```
foreach ($positions as $key => $eachPosition)
{
    if ($eachPosition['date'] == $order['date']) 
    {
        unset(positions[$key]);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete the `$position['date']` value; instead of using `unset($positions[$key])` you could do the following :

```
foreach ($positions as $key => $position) {
    if ($position['date'] == $order['date']) {
        unset($position['date']);
    }    
}
```

**NB** : I removed the reference in the `foreach` loop because according to your example it's not used and can cause unexpected behaviours ([PHP foreach by reference causes weird glitch when going through array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810168/php-foreach-by-reference-causes-weird-glitch-when-going-through-array-of-objects)).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($positions as $position) {
  ($position['date'] == $order['date']) ? unset($position['date']) : '';   
}
```

I hope help you. :)