# Modify array values in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I was wondering if it is possible to edit the current object that's being handled within a `foreach` loop

I'm working with an array of objects `$questions` and I want to go through and look for the answers associated with that question object in my db. So for each question go fetch the answer objects and update the current `$question` **inside** my `foreach` loop so I can output/process elsewhere.

```
foreach($questions as $question){
    $question['answers'] = $answers_model->get_answers_by_question_id($question['question_id']);
}
```

Comment: As both ArtjomKurapov and @topener suggested I was looking for 'pass by reference' using the & sign. Thanks chaps :) have a nice day

Answer (score 267, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this

```
foreach($questions as $key => $question){
    $questions[$key]['answers'] = $answers_model->get_answers_by_question_id($question['question_id']);
}
```

This way you save the key, so you can update it again in the main `$questions` variable

or

```
foreach($questions as &$question){
```

Adding the `&` will keep the `$questions` updated. But I would say the first one is recommended even though this is shorter (see comment by Paystey)

Per [the PHP `foreach` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Comment: Nice! so the & sign will pass by reference? is that the correct terminology?

Comment: you are missing part with passing entire `$question` variable into get_answers_by_question_id()

Comment: @ArtjomKurapov what do you mean? What part

Comment: References in `foreach` is really not recommended, the way the `foreach` passes around the value part of the loop results in unpredicatble behaviour. It may be longer but you're far safer using method 1 here.

Comment: @Topener well he needs $question to be updated inside `get_answers_by_question_id`.. and you are just passing its id

Comment: @ArtjomKurapov I think either you or me misunderstood the question. Thats not what I see he asked

Comment: @Topener right.. I thought `get_answers_by_question_id` does more than just fetch data from DB and actually changes `$question` inside too

Comment: I've found that both methods above work however considering what @Paystey has said I've used the Key Value pair type loop instead of the by reference, it seems messy having the use unset($question) after the loop

Comment: I just spent a perplexed hour debugging an issue caused by using a reference in a foreach. I re-used the same variable name for a second foreach call - as I'd passed the first by reference, it kept modifying the last item in the array! Using an explicit index wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: @Paystey can you cite your sources or give a detailed explaination ?

Comment: Why would manipulating references be unsafe? Is C/C++ where you have to manipulate references everywhere unsafe? It's up to you to make it safe or not, not the language.

Comment: @BabyAzerty: Paystey didn't say references "in general", but in `foreach`, regarding horror like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach (@Nico, FYI, too.)

Answer (score 10):

Surely using `array_map` and if using a container implementing `ArrayAccess` to derive objects is just a smarter, semantic way to go about this?

Array map semantics are similar across most languages and implementations that I've seen. It's designed to return a modified array based upon input array element (high level ignoring language compile/runtime type preference); a loop is meant to perform more logic.

For retrieving objects by ID / PK, depending upon if you are using SQL or not (it seems suggested), I'd use a filter to ensure I get an array of valid PK's, then implode with comma and place into an SQL `IN()` clause to return the result-set. It makes one call instead of several via SQL, optimising a bit of the `call->wait` cycle. Most importantly my code would read well to someone from any language with a degree of competence and we don't run into mutability problems.

```
<?php

$arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
$arr2 = array_map(function($value) { return is_int($value) ? $value*2 : $value; }, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
var_dump($arr2);
```

vs

```
<?php

$arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
foreach($arr as $i => $item) {
    $arr[$i] = is_int($item) ? $item * 2 : $item;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

If you know what you are doing will never have mutability problems (bearing in mind if you intend upon overwriting `$arr` you could always `$arr = array_map` and be explicit.

Comment: Much more intuitive than doing a foreach - this is exactly what this function is designed for.

Comment: Except that you don't have access to the key.