# Element doesn't get added to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following code that loops trough an array called projects and each project is an associative array. Then I get the image properties and then I want to add a new element to this associative array with the image properties. But it doesn't get added.

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $image_dimensions = array(getimagesize('data/'.$project['base_image']));
    $project['image_dimensions'] = $image_dimensions;
}
```

Why isn't `$project['image_dimensions']` getting added to `$project`?

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/q/10121483/1741542

Comment: thank you second reference was the solution!, if you want to be the answer of this question write one and ill accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this one.
You need to add with all projects all key.

```
foreach ($projects as $key => $project) {
    $image_dimensions = array(getimagesize('data/'.$project['base_image']));
    $projects[$key]['image_dimensions'] = $image_dimensions;
}
```