# PHP - how to update values in the multiple dimensional array

Tags: php

I created multiple dimensional array and tried to update count value for certain condition as below but not working.

```
$test[] = [
           'firstNm' => 'luke'
           ,'lastNm' => 'Lee'
           ,'count' => 10

         ];

$test[] = [
           'firstNm' => 'John'
           ,'lastNm' => 'Doe'
           ,'count' => 20
          ];

    foreach ($test as $test01)
    {
     if ($test01['firstNm'] === 'John'){
      $test01['count'] += 70 ;}
    }
```

Looking forward to your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Not one of your questions you have marked as answered...one day people will stop answering your questions.

Comment: check using echo "<pre>";
print_r($test01); at last

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Modify current object in foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121483/php-modify-current-object-in-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are increasing the value but missing to reasign to the same array. Try this one.

```
   $test[] = [
           'firstNm' => 'luke'
           ,'lastNm' => 'Lee'
           ,'count' => 10

         ];

$test[] = [
           'firstNm' => 'John'
           ,'lastNm' => 'Doe'
           ,'count' => 20
          ];

    foreach ($test as $key => $test01)
    { 
     if ($test01['firstNm'] === 'John'){
       $test[$key]['count'] += 70 ;
      }
    }

print_r($test);
```

Comment: @LukeLee Please accept and upvote if this answer help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm going to upvote it, as @LukeLee is not accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121483/php-modify-current-object-in-foreach-loop#answer-10121508), which cites the PHP manual page for [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)</sup>

So you could iterate over the array elements *by-reference*:

```
foreach ($test as &$test01)
{
    if ($test01['firstNm'] === 'John'){
        $test01['count'] += 70 ;
    }
}
```

See this illustrated [on Teh Playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/iBsuNmLfFD8rdBfz).

Otherwise you can iterate using the *key*=>*value* syntax:

```
foreach ($test as $index=>$test01)
{
     if ($test01['firstNm'] === 'John'){
         $test[$index]['count'] += 70 ;
     }
}
```