# Updating Session array in php on page submit in php

Tags: php, arrays, session

First of all I've seen multiple threads and questions. but still I'm stuck at it. so what I'm doing

> Firstly I'm filling my session array through this on **add to cart
>   page**

```
        $_SESSION['food_id']=$get_id;
        $_SESSION['food_name']=$get_name;
        $_SESSION['food_price']=$get_price;
        $_SESSION['food_image']=$get_image;
        $_SESSION['food_quantity']=1;
        $_SESSION['food_discount']=$get_discount;

        $cart = array (
        'food_id' => $_SESSION['food_id'],
        'food_name' => $_SESSION['food_name'],
        'food_price'=> $_SESSION['food_price'],
        'food_image'=> $_SESSION['food_image'],
        'food_quantity' => $_SESSION['food_quantity'],
        'food_discount' => $_SESSION['food_discount']
        );

        $_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart;
```

> Then I'm retrieving and displaying the cart array in cart.php page
>   through this

```
              $total="";
              $item_total="";
              $item_discount="";
              $item_total_quantity="";
              $order_total="";
              $total_discount="";
               if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
                foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {

                    //Get Cart Subtotal Before calculating discount
                      $total += $item['food_price'];

                      $item_total_quantity=$item['food_price']*$item['food_quantity'];

                      //Get Item discount
                        $item_discount = ($item['food_discount']/100)*$item_total_quantity;
                        //Get Item total
                     $item_total=$item_total_quantity-$item_discount;
                     //Get total quantity
                      $food_quantity=$item['food_total_quantity'];

                      $order_total += $item_total;
                      $total_discount += $item_discount;
               ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><a href="menu_single.php?q=<?php echo $item['food_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo 'img/menu/'.$item['food_image']; ?>" alt=""><?php echo $item['food_name']; echo $key; ?></a> </td>
                  <td><?php echo $item['food_price']; ?> $</td>
                  <td>
                     <span class="total"> <?php echo $item['food_quantity']; ?></span>
                      <!-- End input group minus & plus --></td>
                   <td><?php echo $item['food_discount']; ?> %</td>
                   <td><span class="total"> <?php echo $item_total; ?> $ </span> <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
               <?php }} ?>
```

> Now I'm stuck when quantity item changed and button pressed for post
>   back I need to **update quantity based on that value**. What I'm doing currently is.

```
    if(isset($_POST['apply']{
         foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
            //Updating Quantity
               $item['food_quantity']=$_POST['quantity'];
}
```

But I'm not getting my desired result It always display the previous quantity which is set to be 1. I'm about to hit my head on wall right now. Any suggestions would be helpful.

> Edit #1 After reading Rendy Eko Prastiyo's answer. Now I'm able to update session array but it only updates 1 item here is my code

```
                     if(isset($_POST['apply'])){
                        //$cart[] = $_SESSION['cart'];
                     foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
                     echo $_POST['key'];
                     $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['key']]['food_quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
                    //Get Cart Subtotal Before calculating discount
                      $total += $item['food_price'];

                      $item_total_quantity=$item['food_price']*$item['food_quantity'];

                      //Get Item discount
                        $item_discount = ($item['food_discount']/100)*$item_total_quantity;
                        //Get Item total
                     $item_total=$item_total_quantity-$item_discount;
                     //Get total quantity
                      $food_quantity=$item['food_total_quantity'];

                      $order_total += $item_total;
                      $total_discount += $item_discount;

                       echo "<pre>";
                         print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
                       echo "</pre>";
                     }
                    }
```

> Here is print_r result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [food_id] => 5
            [food_name] => New Item
            [food_price] => 14
            [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
            [food_quantity] => 9
            [food_discount] => 10
            [food_total_quantity] => 21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [food_id] => 5
            [food_name] => New Item
            [food_price] => 14
            [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
            [food_quantity] => 1
            [food_discount] => 10
            [food_total_quantity] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [food_id] => 5
            [food_name] => New Item
            [food_price] => 14
            [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
            [food_quantity] => 1
            [food_discount] => 10
            [food_total_quantity] => 21
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [food_id] => 5
            [food_name] => New Item
            [food_price] => 14
            [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
            [food_quantity] => 9
            [food_discount] => 10
            [food_total_quantity] => 21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [food_id] => 5
            [food_name] => New Item
            [food_price] => 14
            [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
            [food_quantity] => 1
            [food_discount] => 10
            [food_total_quantity] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [food_id] => 5
            [food_name] => New Item
            [food_price] => 14
            [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
            [food_quantity] => 1
            [food_discount] => 10
            [food_total_quantity] => 21
        )

)    

Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [food_id] => 5
                [food_name] => New Item
                [food_price] => 14
                [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
                [food_quantity] => 9
                [food_discount] => 10
                [food_total_quantity] => 21
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [food_id] => 5
                [food_name] => New Item
                [food_price] => 14
                [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
                [food_quantity] => 1
                [food_discount] => 10
                [food_total_quantity] => 21
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [food_id] => 5
                [food_name] => New Item
                [food_price] => 14
                [food_image] => dishes2.jpg
                [food_quantity] => 1
                [food_discount] => 10
                [food_total_quantity] => 21
            )

    )
```

Comment: *"Any suggestions would be helpful"* - Error reporting, var_dump, echo, html source, etc.

Comment: I dont see a `session_start()` anywhere so I have to ask do you have one in all the scripts

Comment: @RiggsFolly 99 times out of a 100, they say they started it; surprised? Edit: I'm not.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10121483/1741542

Comment: I have started session it is just the business logic. I am stuck with updating

Comment: at least read the title of question. I am stuck with updating session array. so I have tried var_dump proint_r everything

Comment: obviously if session wasn't started so how could I fill the session array

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to update Session array. @PhpDude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not passed by reference in `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item)`, therefore, when you set `$item['food_quantity'] = $_POST['quantity']` inside the loop, the `$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['food_quantity']` is not modified. There are 2 solutions, set the `$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['food_quantity']` directly, or pass the `$item` in `$_SESSION['cart']` by reference.

Set the `$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['food_quantity']` directly:

```
if (isset($_POST['apply'] {
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
        // Updating quantity.
        $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['food_quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
    }
}
```

Pass the `$item` in `$_SESSION['cart']` by reference:

```
if (isset($_POST['apply'] {
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => &$item) {
        // Updating quantity.
        $item['food_quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use pass by reference, note the difference between `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item)` and `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => &$item)` (add `&` before `$item`, which means `$item` is passed by reference of `$_SESSION['cart'][$key]`).

Comment: Yes I tried this and it works. but when i refresh the page it works. any idea or would i post my whole code of cart ?

Comment: What do you mean with `but when i refresh the page it works` ?

Comment: When i update the session array on post it updates but when i refresh the page then i get my desired result.

Comment: And second thing it only updates the one item quantity at a time not every item

Comment: Do you mean when you post an update that code works, but when you refresh page (with `resend data`) it re-updated the session? You need to use `redirect` after updating the session to avoid it.

Comment: Yeah i handle that. but it is not updating whole array let me put the edit then you can re evaluate

Comment: I don't know why put it is displaying 3 array. Quite stuck at it. will you review the edits

Comment: Where does $_SESSION['cart'] array keys come from? You seem to miss-understand in `$key`, which I don't think it is the item id.

Comment: $_session['cart'] array comes from add to cart page which i already post in  question. secondly i pass $key as a hidden element and retrieve in update.

Comment: You mention only the update action, not the add action when the $_SESSION['cart'] is empty: `if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {`. I need to know the `else` part.

Comment: there is no else part. First I'm displaying all cart items then i'm checking if it updates so update the cart. why should i need else part ?

Comment: If you define the array keys as default incremental array keys, you have to find the key by looping through it. I have updated the answer to fit your need. Could you update your question with the array values of your posted data? Eg. using `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: It's been finally done. I need to use else thanks for your guidance marking it as a correct answer.