# I cant add any key value to my nested arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, nested

I have $monTab, an array with nested arrays like this in php :

```
array (size=12)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-01-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '29' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'mon' => string '2018-02-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'nb_argus' => string '21' (length=2)
  2 =>
```

I am simply trying to add this new pair of key value to each of the nested arrays :

```
'tx'  => int '50' (length=2)
```

So i've built a for each like that :

```
foreach($monTab as $item) {
      $item["tx"] = 50;
}
```

It doesnt work at all, var_dump($monTab) shows that nothing has happened !

the tx key is not added at all, the value is not added at all to my arrays  !!

Comment: Use `foreach($monTab as &$item) {...`

Comment: `foreach($monTab as $key => $item) {
      $monTab[$key]["tx"] = 50;
}` works too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP foreach change original array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024616/php-foreach-change-original-array-values)

Comment: Thank you Mohammad , it is now working, you are good ! Have a nice day !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Modify current object in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121483/php-modify-current-object-in-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the side effect of using pass by reference with foreach(...), using [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) may be an idea.

```
array_walk($monTab, function(&$m){
    $m['tx'] = 50; 
});
```