# Replace every string in multidimensional array if conditions matched

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok so I have an array look like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => order_date.Year
        [1] => =
        [2] => 2024
    ),
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => order_date.Quarter
        [1] => =
        [2] => 1
    )
)
```

What I want to do is, in any element of this multidimensional array I want to replace any string that have a `.` with removing everything after `.`

So the new array should look like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => order_date
        [1] => =
        [2] => 2024
    ),
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => order_date
        [1] => =
        [2] => 1
    )
)
```

I have tried doing this,

```
foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $variable = substr($value[0], 0, strpos($value[0], "."));
        $value[0] = $variable;
    }
}
print_r($filter);
```

I'm getting `$value[0]` as order_date but can't figure out how to assign it to `$filter` array without affecting  other values in array;

Comment: What you've described is a task, not a problem. Not showing us your attempts to solve your tasks will lead to bad reactions. Would you please add your current attempts?

Comment: @Cid I have submitted failed attempt. Sorry I just couldn't get it to working so I asked it here.

Comment: Not really understand what's your problem. You already change `$value[0]` so why  not just simple assign to `$filter` by `$filter[$key] = $value` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$value` variable is not linked with the original array in the foreach loop.
You can make a reference to the original array by using ampersand "&"

```php
foreach ($filter as $key => &$value) { ... }
```

Or you can use old school key nesting

```php
$filter[$key][0] = $variable;
```

Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121508/9429832

Comment: Thanks man. I haven't noticed it. Also didn't knew I can use reference in PHP too. Also can you up vote question?

Answer (score 0):

this will take off values after . in every element of any multidimensional array.

```
// $in is the source multidimensional array
array_walk_recursive ($in, function(&$item){
    if (!is_array($item)) {
        $item = preg_replace("/\..+$/", "", $item);
    }
});
```