# PHP Strings: How to use curly braces to parse objects returned by functions

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have a function that returns an object. How to write a string that parses a member of the object returned by that function (the function is in a different namespace)?
This is what I'm trying to do but the string used on **echo** is invalid.

```
namespace security;
function &get_user() {
    $user = (object) array('email' => 'abcd@abcd.com', 'name' => 'John Doe');
    return $user;
}

echo "<li><p class=\"navbar-text\">Welcome, {${\security\get_user()}->name}</p></li>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, a few things:

- You cannot [interpolate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) functions/method inside strings. Only variables are allowed.
- When you create a [namespace](http://php.net/namespace) you only have to refer to it when outside the namespace.
- Do not use [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) (`&`) unless you understand what they do. In PHP references work differently than in most other languages.

This is how the code will look like.

```
// We define the namespace here. We do not need
// to refer to it when inside the namespace.
namespace security;

// Objects and arrays are always passed by
// reference, so you should not use & here
function get_user() {
    return (object) array(
        'email' => 'abcd@abcd.com',
        'name' => 'John Doe',
    );
}
// We need to get the value from the function
// before interpolating it in the string
$user = get_user();

// There are a few ways to interpolate in PHP
// This is for historical and functional reasons
// Interpolating array items is, "{$arr['key']}"
echo "<li><p class=\"navbar-text\">Welcome, $user->name</p></li>";
echo "<li><p class=\"navbar-text\">Welcome, {$user->name}</p></li>";
```

Comment: More precisely, you can use functions/methods inside strings, but they are expected to return a variable name.

Comment: It is also possible to use this: `echo "<li><p class=\"navbar-text\">Welcome, " . get_user()->name . "</p></li>";` if the more-concise source code is truly needed.

Comment: Actually the `echo` is inside another php file and namespace. That's why I put namespace. I read the docs and think I understand references and their caveats (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach) but I still don't understand the implications of returning a reference on the `get_user` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do anything more complex then accessing an object member inside a string; it is hard to read and hard to maintain (e.g. your IDE will probably miss it when doing refactoring). That said, just for the fun of it:

```
function get_user() {
    $user = (object) array('email' => 'abcd@abcd.com', 'name' => 'John Doe');
    return $user;
}

echo "<li><p class=\"navbar-text\">Welcome, {${($x = \security\get_user()->name) ? 'x' : 'x'}}</p></li>";
```

The variable assignment is necessary here - you can use functions and just about anything else inside curly braces in a string, but their result will be interpreted as a variable name. Basically, `$str = "{${<some code>}}";` is equivalent to `$name = eval("<some code>"); $str = $$name;"`.