# Unexpected data change due to reference variable

Tags: php

This code is causing unexpected array content change. What could be the reason of this:

```
<?php

$arr[] = array('a', 'b');
$arr[] = array('c', 'd');

print_r($arr);
foreach ($arr as &$processed_arr) {

}

foreach ($arr as $processed_arr) {

}

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

)
```

Comment: you should try to do step by step debugging with a watch expression on your array.

Comment: Please make your title describe the problem. "Need help" is not a useful question title.

Comment: you need to post code before that array in order for us to figure out anything - there are too little information as to what is being passed actively to that segment

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Pass by reference in foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can indeed be due to your loop before. `foreach` in php leaves the iteration
variable in scope even after the loop (Awful, I know).

So code like this:

```php
$loop = [1,2,3];

foreach ($loop as &$c) {}

$c = 4;

var_dump($loop);
```

Will result in a `loop` variable containing `[1,2,4]`

The rest of your code doesn't look like it could be the cause of this. Of course
the implementation of `status` is free to do whatever but given the name it seems
highly unlikely imo. :)

Next time it might help to post more of the context. It's good to try to trim down
the code posted like you have done, but if the posted code no longer exposes the
problem (which yours does not) it makes it much harder to guess what's wrong.