# PHP foreach loop modifies array without any assignment

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, reference

I'm really getting crazy with this since two days now. I'd greatly appreciate if someone could give me a hint. I definitely can't understand why this PHP code:

```
$arr [] = [ "name" => "Chapter 1" ];
$arr [] = [ "name" => "Chapter 2" ];

foreach ( $arr as &$item )
    echo $item['name']."<br>";

echo "============<br>";

foreach ( $arr as $item )
    echo $item['name']."<br>";
```

gives this output:

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
============
Chapter 1
Chapter 1      (I would expect 'Chapter 2' here)
```

It looks like the first loop modifies the array, even though there is no assignment in the loop. Strangely enough, everything works as expected, when I remove the ampersand.

The thing I don't understand is, why is the array getting modified at all, even though I don't do anything with the reference variable '&$item' variable (except echoing it).

I also tried reset() between the loops. But it didn't change anything, and according to the manual it shouldn't be necessary anyway in such a case (at lease from my understanding) because the loops start after each other and are not nested somehow.

Thanks a lot!

Bernd

Comment: remove "&" from &$item in first foreach :-)

Comment: Add `unset($item)` immediately after the first loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Pass by reference in foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach)

Comment: Yes that would be the easiest way :-). But the snippet above is just a piece of code that I've stripped down to show the essential problem. The reason I can't remove it is that in the real code indeed I need to modify the array from within the loop. Of course a 'for' - loop also works well, but I don't like building workarounds just because I don't understand the initial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After any loop completes, the variables used in it still exist. For instance:

```
for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    // do something
}
echo $i; // 10
```

The same applies to references. After the loop is done, `$item` is still a reference to the last item in the array. Thus when you write `foreach($arr as $item)` a second time, you're now using that reference to the last element and repeatedly re-assigning it, which results in the last element of the array being assigned (by reference) the same thing as the second-to-last item.

To fix, be sure to clean up:

```
unset($item); // delete the reference
```

In theory you should clean up after any loop, but in pretty much all other cases it won't matter. It's just that in this case, it does!

Comment: Yes that works. Thanks a lot for your ubelievable fast, good and detailed explanation! Simply great !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can read more here http://pl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

"In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference."

Example:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is not technically getting modified in your code sample, but a reference point is being attached to one of your array values.  If you modify your example to read:

```
$arr [] = [ "name" => "Chapter 1" ];
$arr [] = [ "name" => "Chapter 2" ];
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arr);

foreach ( $arr as &$item )
    echo $item['name']."<br>";

echo "============<br>";

var_dump($arr);

foreach ( $arr as $item )
    echo $item['name']."<br>";

echo $item['name'];
```

You can examine the var dump output and see the reference pointer in the second var dump:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Chapter 1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Chapter 2"
    }
}
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
============
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Chapter 1"
    }
    [1]=>
    &array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "Chapter 2"
    }
}
Chapter 1
Chapter 1
```

My theory is it has something to do with how PHP is handling reference pointers internally.  As others have suggested, just run `unset($item)` in between the loops and you can mitigate the issue.