# Is it safe to append to an array in a while loop?

Tags: php, arrays

There are numerous questions out there about the safety implications of manipulating an array when using `foreach` on it. I can't find any questions on doing this in a while loop, though.

So I wonder, is it safe to do this? Below is an example script in PHP and I'm not sure if this is alright.

```
while ($item = array_pop($array)) {
  findMoreItems($item, $array);
}

function findMoreItems($item, &$array) {
  // Returns null if no more items are found
  $newItem = someFuncFromServer($item);

  if ($newItem) {
    array_push($array, $newItem);
  }
}
```

By safe I mean: can I be sure that no items are skipped in the loop?

Comment: As safe as an infinite loop can be.

Comment: This question is, surprisingly, a lot more in depth than it looks. I could explain it, but I'll probably not explain it good enough. See [here](https://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html) for starters, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach) and [here](https://www.toptal.com/php/10-most-common-mistakes-php-programmers-make). It's not complicated, but it's just tricky to explain properly. And @apokryfos that's not an infinite loop.

Comment: it is a "potential" infinite loop.

Comment: I edited in the obvious, so no: there is no infinite loop considering the data I'm working with.

Comment: Use `$array[] = $newItem;` it's faster than array_push

Comment: The `if` wasn't there when I commented that. @Andrew this is a while loop. A foreach is a completely different story.

Comment: Absolutely, 2 different matters, no doubt about it. OP was asking(from what I can understand) the implications of using `foreach` as opposed to `while` since it's already clarified that `while` has none of the pitfalls of `foreach` which is a specific language construct in php.

Comment: @Andrew I'm actually asking a while loop, and *not* about the foreach loop.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'safe'? 2) Is someFuncFromServer a remote call? You may run into timeouts then really easy :-)

Comment: @BramVanroy I stand corrected then. For the record, I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: The array is always shrinking or staying constant size - therefore it will always terminate if you make sure that at some time there is no more $newItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is essentially equivalent to :

```
$item = array_pop($array);
while ($item) {
  findMoreItems($item, $array);
  $item = array_pop($array)
}

function findMoreItems($item, &$array) {
  // Returns null if no more items are found
  $newItem = someFuncFromServer($item);

  if ($newItem) {
    array_push($array, $newItem);
  }
}
```

Now if you rewrite this in the above way it is obvious that the code will not do anything like copy references or array points or anything like that which is what `foreach` does. `foreach` does that because it relies on the internal array pointer which `array_pop` and `array_push` do not.

Comment: After all I can not think of a way how this could go wrong after all. Your answer regarding foreach is true. Rationally it is totally safe.

However it would be interesting to drive some real life tests with a whole lot of data to see if an error may happen - just to be sure if PHP does not behave unexpectedly.

Comment: I think the much bigger risk is that any bug in `someFuncFromServer`  may cause this to become an infinite loop.