# Last index of pass by reference looped array shown twice

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have this code.

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    // Do stuff to array
}
```

A `var_dump` afterwards shows the last index (107 in this case) of the array has a reference `&`.

```
[107]=>
&array(4) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(2) "bar"
}
```

My problem is that a follow up foreach doesn't show the last index of the array, but instead repeats the second to last index.

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
    // When it gets to 107, it'll just show 106 again
}
```

**Why do I see this behavior and how can I ensure that the second `foreach` includes the last element of the array?**

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach

Comment: @Avihaym Yep that's exactly my problem. Couldn't find it in my searching. This question can be closed as dupe.