# How can I unset an array's children values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a structure identical to:

```
$sidebar_data= [
    'wp_inactive_widgets' => array(),
    'sidebar-1' => array(
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that'
    ),
    'sidebar-2' => array(
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that'
    ),
    'array_version' => 3
];
```

I'm looking to wipe out any **values within the array's keys**, not just the full array with `unset`, so, `sidebar-1, sidebar-2` should be emptied, but kept, to get the desired result:

```
$new_sidebar_data = [
    'wp_inactive_widgets' => array(),
    'sidebar-1' => array(),
    'sidebar-2' => array(),
    'array_version' => 3
];
```

How can I achieve this?

Edit:

I already went through this solution:

```
$sidebar_data= [
    'wp_inactive_widgets' => array(),
    'sidebar-1' => array(
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that'
    ),
    'sidebar-2' => array(
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that',
        'this' => 'that'
    ),
    'array_version' => 3
];
$sidebars_widgets_original_keys = array_keys( $sidebar_data);
$sidebars_widgets_new_structure = [];

foreach( $sidebars_widgets_original_keys as $sidebars_widgets_original_key ) {
    $sidebars_widgets_new_structure[$sidebars_widgets_original_key] = array();
}
```

It works, but it's really ugly and feels counterintuitive to present to anyone.

Comment: All keys, or all keys not including `array_version`, or all keys which are arrays, or ???

Comment: @Nick It doesn't matter in this case, should just keep the keys.

Comment: @Erubiel Not a duplicate. I'm looking to keep the keys of the array.

Comment: yeah, but you can manage each children on the same way, if you are asking for the best way... but maybe you are right, maybe i should have posted it as a comment sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reassign empty array

```
$new_sidebar_data['sidebar-1'] = [];
$new_sidebar_data['sidebar-2'] = [];
```

more dynamic way

```
foreach($new_sidebar_data as &$value) {
    if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 0) {
         $value = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I already went through this method, was just wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: @Erubiel Its not typo its pass by reference.

Comment: @JasminMistry Sorry. It seems your solution works. Care to explain why going for the pass by reference?

Comment: @coolpasta check for is_array and count check to ensure variable is array and not empty

Comment: @coolpasta when you want to change same array inside loop then you can use &. it treat as pointer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach

Comment: @JasminMistry I wonder what the performance implications of re-writing the array on the fly instead of just re-assigning the keys to a new array are. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JasminMistry my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you

```
array_walk($new_sidebar_data, function (&$value, $key) {
    if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 0) {
        $value = [];
    }
});
```

Works for all keys starting with "sidebar-"