# Insert a new array inside an Associative Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I tried to insert a new array inside my multidimensional/Associative array. BUt it does not work, neither `array_push()` does. My current code is as follow:

```
$myJson = array(
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Jane Doe', 
    'age' => 26
  ),
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Josélito',
    'age' => 35
  )
);


$myAr = array(
  'id' => 5,
  'channel' => 'pimbaTv',
  'followers' => 15014
);

foreach($myJson AS $js) {
  $js['event'][] = $myAr;
  //$js['event'] = $myAr;
}
```

So I would have something like this:

```
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Jane Doe', 
    'age' => 26,
    'event' => array(
       'id' => 5,
       'channel' => 'pimbaTv',
       'followers' => 15014
     );
  ),
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Josélito',
    'age' => 35,
    'event' => array(
       'id' => 5,
       'channel' => 'pimbaTv',
       'followers' => 15014
     );
  )
```

I'm trying everything I can find but still no solution.

Comment: Share what you've tried please.

Comment: in loops where you have array without object you must explicitly use reference & for values. Otherwise the table won't be modified.

Comment: @Robert Is there a reason to use `reference` instead of the example showed by @Madhur ? Because both gives me the same result.

Comment: in @Madhur he modifies the original array using key addressing both will do the same the drawback of reference is that the reference $value remains after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access your original array `$myJson` using `$key` from the loop, for assigning new values. By default, `$value` inside a foreach loop, are not passed by reference.

Do the following:

```
foreach($myJson AS $key => $value) {
  $myJson[$key]['event'] = $myAr;
}
```

You can see other answers as well, [utilizing passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro happy to help :) You may consider it as accepted answer (green tick :)

Comment: Would there be a reason to do not use this approach over the `pass by reference` showed below? Thanks!

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro pass by reference carries a risk of inadvertently modifying the other contents of original array (which we dont want)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya in both cases you modify original content of array. This is only a little bit safier because reference remains after the loop is executed which may lead to hard to track errors.

Comment: @Robert I am talking about some other **inadvertent** changes, other than the changes we are already doing!

Answer (score 2):

You can use pass by reference to array in `for` loop like this. For reference [PHP Pass by reference in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach)

```
foreach($myJson AS &$js) {
    $js['event'] = $myAr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In new php versions, you should use references to edit its content.

Instead of doing :

```
foreach($myJson AS $js) {
    $js['event'][] = $myAr;
}
```

You shoud do :

```
foreach($myJson AS &$js) {
    $js['event'][] = $myAr;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

"In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference."

Comment: Would there be a reason to use `references` instead of the example provided by Madhur ? WOuld this be `Good Practice` or maybe something related to performance?

Comment: If you use copy ( as in Madhur answer ), you would create new objects on each loop, even if you don't use them.
So, yeah, this is a performance issue to use copies instead of references, even if you just read data from arrays. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The array_push() function is normally used to push new data in the array but must have a sequential index: $arr[0] , $ar[1].. etc.

You cannot use it in associative array directly. But looking to your array structure, since your sub array have this kind of index you can still use array push but you must specify the index. This is an example:

```
array_push($myJson["event"], $myAr);
```

Hope it is more clear for you.