# How to replace array key in multidemensional array in PHP

Tags: php

In a multidimensional array, how do I replace a null key with "None" ?

Here is an example:

```
  'None' → array(1) {
     [""] => array(4) {
      [0] => array(10) {
       'store' → str•2 '11'
       'supplier_number' → str•4 '6303'
    }
```

Should look like:

```
   'None' → array(1) {
     'None' => array(4) {
      [0] => array(10) {
       'store' → str•2 '11'
       'supplier_number' → str•4 '6303'
    }
```

Comment: When constructing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr['None']['None'] = $arr['None'][''];

unset($arr['None']['']);
```

See also here: [PHP rename array keys in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212948/php-rename-array-keys-in-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function

```
function rename_empty_keys($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            $arr[$key] = rename_empty_keys($val);
        }
        if(empty($key)) {
            $arr['None'] = $arr[$key];
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: This is not really needed if the OP only wants to change one key.

Comment: OP specifically states "multidimensional array". The code example is ambiguous. It would e.g. be necessary to change `arrray(''=>array(''=>1))` into `array('None'=>array('None'=>1))`