# Changing the array index [0] to [some-name] PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Please take a look at the following array..

```
Array 
( 
  [0] => Array 
  ( 
    [fee_id] => 15 
    [fee_amount] => 308.5 
    [year] => 2009 
  ) 

  [1] => Array 
  ( 
    [fee_id] => 14 
    [fee_amount] => 308.5 
    [year] => 2009 
  ) 

)
```

I Need output like this,

```
    Array 
    ( 
     [rfp] => Array 
      ( 
        [fee_id] => 15 
        [fee_amount] => 308.5 
        [year] => 2009 
      ) 

     [user] => Array 
      ( 
       [fee_id] => 14 
       [fee_amount] => 308.5 
       [year] => 2009 
      ) 

    )
```

Is there any possibilities to do that..?
I read this [PHP rename array keys in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212948/php-rename-array-keys-in-multidimensional-array)

But it explains about the renaming of array keys, But I need this to implement in my live application.

Please help me..

Comment: How you use  find method?

Comment: I used for my custom needs in my application. In what case you're asking for find method..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
<?php
$arr[0]['fee_id']=12;
$arr[0]['fee_amount']=308.5;
$arr[0]['year']=2009;

$arr[1]['fee_id']=14;
$arr[1]['fee_amount']=308.5;
$arr[1]['year']=2009;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";


$arr2['rfp']=$arr[0];
$arr2['user']=$arr[1];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr2);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to implement can you explain in detail as a function.

Answer (score 6):

Just build a new array with the data:

```
$newArray=[
    'rfp'=>$oldArray[0],
    'user'=>$oldArray[1]
];
```

if you really need to, you can then overwrite the old variable to hold the new array:

```
$oldArray = $newArray;
```

Comment: You could even skip the overwriting step by just redefining `$oldArray`. The values will exist until the array is overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

This will be as easy as screwing in the imaginary lightbulb.

```
$array['key_name_you_want'] = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);
```

This will set all `$array[0]` values to `$array['key_name_you_want']` and then unset `$array[0]` so it will no longer be in `$array`.

Comment: Plus one for the bizarre idiom.